# Deployment Problem with Webpack & Github Pages

Tags: javascript, webpack, github-pages

I've got a little API App built with Webpack. To publish it on GitHub Pages I've installed the npm package gh-pages.

Everything works fine, the dist-folder is pushed correctly and when I open the live-version the index and scss files are displayed as well.

The problem now is that my bundle.js doesn't load. So the whole functionality is not active. Another thing I've discovered is that my media queries doesn't pop in as well.

Would be great if anyone could help me fixing that issue!

My Repository:

https://github.com/jeanmarc5592/Cocktail-API-Project

My webpack.config.js File:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const multi = require('multi-loader');

module.exports = {
    entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/js/index.js'],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'js/bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist'
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          filename: 'index.html',
          template: './src/index.html'  
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {  
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: {
                    loader: multi('style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader')
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    'file-loader'
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in your console or network tab in the browser?

Comment: No, I'm getting no errors ...

Comment: I cloned your project in my local system. You already have dist folder. When I serve that folder, the project doesn't work but when I rebuild the project using either of npm run dev or npm run build and then serve the folder, it is working fine. Is the same thing happening with you also?

Comment: SOLVED: I've removed the local repository and rebuilt it using npm run build and npm run deploy ...everything works fine. Thanks a lot for helping me out!